# How can I disable jobs in the Quartz JDBCJobStore?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

What is the best way to disable a job in the JDBCJobStore without deleting it's job or trigger records and without wiping the cron expression?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [scheduler.pauseJob()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#pauseJob(org.quartz.JobKey)) or [scheduler.pauseTrigger()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#pauseTrigger(org.quartz.TriggerKey)).

Alternatively you can use the following SQL script:

```
UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = "PAUSED"
```

Comment: Works in Quartz.Net too!      Here is some pseudo code just to demonstrate :    (in c#, java would be similar, except for generics )                           IList<string> jobGroupNames = sched.GetJobGroupNames();
                    GroupMatcher<JobKey> groupMatcher= GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(jobGroupNames.FirstOrDefault());
                    Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> keys = sched.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
                    sched.PauseJob(keys.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Whether the script `UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = "PAUSED"` is documented by Quartz any where? Is this perfect way to do that without any regression?

Comment: Writing into the tables is not the best solution: see [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/best-practices.html#never-write-directly-to-quartzs-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pauseJob` or `pauseJobGroup` methods of `JobStore`.