# Turn off quartz jobs scheduling from database

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

There are some cron jobs which i don't want to execute on a QA environment as it unnecessary occupies heap space and slows down the system.

Is there any debug variable Quartz provides through which i can control the execution of jobs from db ?

How can it be achieved ?

Comment: there is a Endtime field in Triggers table. I think by changing it you can control the execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430710/how-can-i-disable-jobs-in-quartz-jdbcjobstore

Answer (score 1):

in the triggers table there is a column in the name of trigger_state . change that column for desirable record to ERROR. usually the value of column is WAITING

Answer (score 0):

I didnt do this via the database but you can update the quartz config file and remove /comment out the triggers section

```
<!--<property name="triggers">-->
    <!--<list>-->
        <!--<ref bean="myJobTrigger"/>-->         
    <!--</list>-->
<!--</property>-->
```