# Pause quartz trigger from database

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using SpringMVC, Quartz 2.2.1 with Mysql 5.6.15.

I have a scheduled task that use some web resources. Now the resources are not available, so I need to ignore the task temporarily, waiting for them to be back.

I think changing the code is too much for such a minor issue. While knowing it's not recommended, I guess altering the Quartz Mysql database is the best way to go.
I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439108/4841235) suggesting :

```
UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = "PAUSED"
```

the answer is 7 years ago and the replyer not responding, I tried to find the doc saying so, but no luck. I wanna know :

1. Is this the right way to do, without any side-effect?
2. What does `QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS` table for? Do I need to alter it?

Comment: I guess its not a perfect solution. You shouldn't alter Quartz inner state db data. Why not to use `scheduler.pauseJob()` or `scheduler.pauseTrigger().` as he suggested?

Comment: @yishaiz Because `scheduler.pauseJob()` requires to alter the code, pack the jar, commit the code (messing up the code base with a lot of `work-around` commits), publish to production (need some bureaucracy) , and the situation may recover/reoccur any time later.

Comment: So I understand that it's a production env issue. Maybe you could expose an API for your inner use, for pausing/resuming the job. The API will always be there and won't require new deploy/commits. You can also write a new isolated app that does only that, for your inner use.

Comment: And if you still want to use direct access to db, you should debug Quartz code to unsure you replicate the same way that Quartz does the `pauseJob`

Comment: @matrix Did it work for you? I also have to simillar task.

Comment: @Asrinivas Sorry to response late. I no longer work on that since that and never know the best practice. But directly alter quartz database is not a good idea, might cause side-effect.